# How to add date picker control to my toolbox?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I am using visual studio 2005 and I have added Datepicker dll in my bin folder of sample project.And By doing right click on solution Explorer Add:references,choosed the that dll.But I want display that control in my toolbar.Does I need to create tab for it.Or it automatically get created.or need to go to toolbox then right click anywhere in the toolbox area click choose item and then select server control dll from there and it should appear in toolbox.Suppose if I done this for my sample project.But when next time I am using other project using vs 2005,that control can be seen in toolbar.I know we have to add reference into project for dll but for control need to create tab once again?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to open up a new instance of visual studio right click your toolbox, select Add tab, then you right click the newly added tab and select Choose  items, browse to the dll and  add the dll, this should add the date picker for all projects, at least it worked for me